# Can a WinForms Startup Form Be Used As The Composite Root For The Unity Container

Tags: winforms, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, unity-container

I have a WinForms application setup as an N-Layered solution in Visual Studio. 
I would like to use the first startup form in this WinForms application as the location where my Unity registrations and Resolves take place.  This would be right in the initialization step as the form is beginning to startup. If I place the Unity setup here then I won't need to be concerned about passing in parameters to the startup form from a separate project.  The startup form is basically the main form of all forms in the WinForms application. All other forms are spawned from the main form either directly or indirectly.

If Unity is setup in the main form, I can register all the interface classes intended to be injected into all other sub forms and project classes here.  Would doing this cause any serious problems or would this approach work out fine?

I like this approach because it would mean I don't have to have a separate project created just for the purpose of setting up Unity and having to register all interface classes in that project to be passed to the first startup form.

Answer (score 2):

The responsibility of the main form is UI related, it interacts with the user.

If you follow the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle), then you don't want to add another responsibility (composing the application) into the main form.

To make it more clear, now there are at least two reasons to change the main form class:

1. you need to change how the UI looks
2. you need to compose the application in a different way

Since your concern is that you don't want to have a special project just for the composition root, you can still use the same Windows Forms project by putting the composition root in the `Main` method in the `Program` class in the `Program.cs` file (in case of C# language) file which actually creates an instance of the main form and runs it.